# Minecraft keepInventory command not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I began a new map with cheats enabled, and tried to use the keepInventory command, but it's not working, i.e. I still drop items after death.

I typed the command right, as I copied it directly from the wiki and pasted it in-game. I also tried it on a server, but its still not working.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: checked if you had a space at the end of the command? a known failure :P

Comment: Tell us how you wrote it out and then it may be easier to answer the question, if you don't tell us exactly what you did it may be difficult for us to help you.

Comment: "I typed the command right" Are you sure? Paste it here and we'll see.